# Way to animate between two numbers that's more performant than .animate();

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I'm trying to animate from the number '1' to '100' using a jquery technique I've seen several places online. It works OK, but Firefox has some serious issues with this, and I know jQuery's .animate() as a whole isn't the greatest.

The span '#headline-number' starts out as a one, which is why the age range begins at 2.

```
function incrementNumber(number) {
    if (number.length) {

        number.addClass('is-visible'); // Triggers 500ms opacity transition in my css

        setTimeout( function(){
            $({ages: 2}).animate({ages: 100}, {
              duration: 1500,
              easing:'swing',
              step: function() {
                  number.text(Math.round(this.ages));
              }
            });
        }, 510);
    }
}

 incrementNumber($('#headline-number'));
```

Are there any alternative techniques to accomplish this? Either with jQuery, or just vanilla javascript? Thanks!

Comment: I've never tried it myself, but give [move.js](http://visionmedia.github.io/move.js/) a go. Sounds like it might use CSS3 transitions where available.

Comment: can you really animate two contents like that?

Comment: Yes, you can animate values in jQuery. It's kind of different, but here's the article I saw it in: http://www.josscrowcroft.com/2011/code/jquery-animate-increment-decrement-numeric-text-elements-value/

Comment: i mean, this will fire a bunch and replace the text regularly, but i don't think it's animating anything, by which i mean showing something in-between the two. when animating white to black we see gray, but what intermediary value is between "A" and "B"?

Comment: Why 'animate' instead of just count and display? What are your ultimate goals on the page?

Comment: What I'm trying to accomplish is to have the number 1 go to 100 on the page (and show all numbers in between). The animation, or in between values, are all the numbers between 1 and 100. In the end this should kind of look like a counter or ticker.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up going with this approach of using a setTimeout, incrementing the number, and clearing it once I got to  a certain point.

```
function incrementNumber(numberValue, number) {
    if(numberValue == 100) {
        clearTimeout(numberAnimation);
        return;
    }

    numberValue++

    if (numberValue > number.text()) {
        number.text(numberValue);
    }

    var numberAnimation = setTimeout(function() {
        incrementNumber(numberValue, number);
    }, 10);
}
```

The `number` in this case is a selector in the DOM, `numberValue` is the starting number for your animation. The text of the selector and `numberValue` should match. The animation I used can be seen here: http://willguldin.com/one-hundred-ages/

I'd like to add some easing to this, so that as it gets closer to finishing, it slows down, but I deciding this was close enough to the effect I wanted.

Comment: Take a look at tweenmax, it has all kinds of different easings and is extremely performant. I used it on a production site and it works flawlessy while easing two different values from small integers to millions, even on mobile.